# Animations in Matplotlib: Making a "Loading Bar"

Tags: matplotlib, pygtk

Note this example:

http://laplace.ucv.cl/Cursos/FisicaExperimental_2/Old/Python/Programas/strip_chart_demo.py

where an oscilloscope is animated out.  Is there any way to use Matplotlib to control the pace that the  graph is animated? I am trying to make a loading/progress bar and would like to control how quickly the loading bar expands. What I have tried is to change the line

`gobject.idle_add(scope.update)`

to

`gobject.timeout_add(100, scope.update)`

but that causes the line to not draw at all.

Any tips?

Comment: are you using [matplotlib.animation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html?highlight=animation) and checked the [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html)?

Comment: Is `scope.update` being called?

Comment: @Francesco, yes I am using matplotlib.animation and checked the examples. It says nothing about slowing or speeding up this rendering.

Comment: @ecatmur, yes scope.update is being called.